# how to render an html page in other html page as a popup window on a button click using mvc5 asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

```
  <body>
    <p>Click the button to show the dialog.</p>

       <button onclick="myFunction()">Show dialog</button>

       <dialog id="myDialog" style="position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px">@RenderPage("popup.cshtml")  </dialog>


    <script>
       function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal();
      }
```

it is rendering my page correctly but the problem is that dialog box. i dont want the dialog box i just want  to render my  partialview page  .please help me to do so .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HTML page,you can link to another HTML page using `href` attribute on the button which will direct you to the other page.

```
<button>
     <a href="otherpage.html">Show Dialog</a>
</button>
```

Comment: i have a partial view and i have to render this view in my main view as a popup window .

Comment: Refer this. It might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720412/load-partial-view-on-clicking-href-link-on-the-same-page